# How are different religions correlated to progressives?

Tags: united-states, religion

Are there some data or studies on the religious statuses of progressive politicians (social democrats, democratic socialists, Green party members, ...) in US? For example, I heard that Bernie Sanders is either a believer of Judaism or an atheist.

How are different religions correlated to progressivism in person?

Particularly, for those progressives who are Christians, how are they distributed over denominations? (Not just Mainline vs Evangelical.)

Comment: There have always been two relatively equal branches of liberalism in the U.S..  One secular coming out of the enlightenment movement of the 18th century.   Which included most of **[the American Founding Fathers](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/52456/61331)**.  The other religious in nature characterized by both Christian(Catholics and Protestants) and Judaism.  Catholics who believe "good works" are necessary to achieve salvation.  and Protestants  such as Walter Rauschenbusch, William Jennings Bryan, Jane Addams, and Ellen Gates Star.

Comment: What's your definition of progressive? Democrat voter, left-wing Democrat (however you define that), moderate Republican, or what?

Comment: @JMS What do Protestants believe, while "Catholics who believe "good works" are necessary to achieve salvation"?

Comment: @StuartF social democrats, democratic socialists, Green party members, ...

Comment: @Tim,  Protestants typically believe faith alone is necessary to achieve salvation.     And just to finish my thought from the previous post.  Judaism teaches a form of charity synonymous with social justice or tzedakah.   Where  acts of charity are divided into 8 levels.  The lowest and least favored is when one is pained by the act of giving.  The highest level is when one gives without being solicited even anonymously.

Answer (score 10):

Since this question is directed at the religious affiliations of politicians a [Pew summary of the religious affiliations of the 118th Congress](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2023/01/03/faith-on-the-hill-2023/) is relevant. It is summarized in this image:

[image]

There are 535 members of Congress in all.

Unsurprisingly, only 3 of 61 non-Christians in Congress (excluding one Republican Messianic Jew whom I would classify as, and who identifies as, a form of Christian) are Republicans. Put another way, 3 out of 271 Republicans in Congress are non-Christian (2 are Jews and 1 is "don't know").

All 9 Mormons are Republican.

There are 4 Republican Orthodox Christians and 4 Democratic party Orthodox Christians.

There are 81 Democrats in Congress who are Catholic and 67 Republicans in Congress who are Catholic.

There are 116 Democrats in Congress who are Protestants and 187 Republicans in Congress who are Protestants.

There is a finer breakdown by party and religious leaning here (from the same source), although it doesn't make a further distinction between historically African-American Protestant denominations (whose Congressional adherents are disproportionately Democrats) and other Protestant denominations, or between historically Southern and historically Northern sub-denominations of historically white Protestant denominations.

[image]

Every single Republican member of the 118th Congress is more conservative (and less progressive) than every single Democrat in Congress.

Comment: the images in your post are again not viewable from PRC.

Comment: @Tim The important bits are also in words.